# Check for multiple patterns preg_replace

Tags: php, preg-replace, query-string

I'm trying to find out if `&page=([0-9]+)` or `page=([0-9]+)` are in a string, and remove them, but I'm getting an error.

My attempt

```
$queryString = '?order=stud_firstname&sort=desc&page=8';
$queryString = preg_replace(array('/&page=([0-9]+)/','/?page=([0-9]+)/'),array('',''),$queryString);
```

My error returned

```
Warning: preg_replace(): Compilation failed: nothing to repeat at offset 0
```

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
$queryString = '?order=stud_firstname&sort=desc&page=8';
echo $queryString = preg_replace('/[&\?]page=([0-9]+)/', '',$queryString);
                                 //^^^^^^ See here '&' OR '?'
```

Useful links:

[Test your regex!](https://regex101.com/)

[regex cheat sheet](http://www.cheatography.com/davechild/cheat-sheets/regular-expressions/)

Comment: Awesome! Thanks! :) Will tick when I can in 10

Comment: @dpDesignz You're welcome! Have a nice day :D (BTW: i updated my answer with 2 useful links!)

Comment: The pipe (or) is not necessary inside of a character class. `[&\?]` already means one of anything from that list. You are essentially just adding pipe as an accepted character so `|page=1` would match. It would be used in a parenthesis group. `(&|\?)` would be the same thing.

Comment: @dpDesignz Note that removing the question mark might lead to unexpected results later on if you add it to a url again.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn you're right! completely forgot that, updated it

Comment: @Rizier123 sorry I just discovered that `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` doesn't have the `?` at the beginning, so it's not removing it if the string is like `?page=8&order=stud_firstname&sort=desc` because the `?` doesn't exist in the string. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: @dpDesignz This should work: `echo $queryString = preg_replace('/&?page=([0-9]+)/', '',$queryString);`  It looks if it has 0 or 1 `&` before `page...` follows

Comment: @Rizier123 hmm no I'm trying that on regex101 and it only matches the first 1 :(. I'm putting this in the regular expression `&?page=([0-9]+)` and this in the test string `page=1&order=stud_firstname&sort=desc&page=8` but it's only getting 1 match

Comment: @dpDesignz Please post the link to your regex101 so i can see what you have tried (On the left side there is a button save regex)

Comment: @dpDesignz :D if you test the regex there and you want all matches not only 1 you have to add the modifier `g` to the regex :D But in php it should work fine (Just hover over the question mark for a second and read the first modifier, `g` as a modifier doesn't exists in normal regex in php only for regex101 for testing)

Comment: to be sure your parameter is correctly bounded, you can use this: `(?:^page=\d+&*(?:&|\z)|&+page=\d+(?=&|$))`